# Adding a button to open up the sidebar and play a specific embedded audio track

Tags: audio, google-sheets-api

I am working on creating a google sheet that has a series of embedded audio tracks in the sidebar. The goal is to have people listen to various audio tracks and code the interviews in the spreadsheet.

It would be awesome if I could include a button in the spread sheet that when clicked will open the sidebar and play a specific audio track?

Thanks in advance!

Here is what I have so far:

```
CODE:


function onOpen(e) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
  .createAddonMenu()
  .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Sidebar')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle(SIDEBAR_TITLE);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import common stylesheet -->
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>

<div class="sidebar branding-below">
    <audio id="player" controls>
      <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?    export=download&id=0BzdQx2zfyYbTUmNWd3M3MF80bGs" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
     <audio id="player" controls>
      <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?    export=download&id=0BzdQx2zfyYbTVWI2V2JXRGRoMVE" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
     <audio id="player" controls>
      <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?    export=download&id=0BzdQx2zfyYbTdW9YelZfYS1vTlU" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
     <audio id="player" controls>
      <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BzdQx2zfyYbTX1RiWE43UVhPN0E" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    <div id="sidebar-status"></div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar bottom">
  <span class="gray branding-text">Docs Add-on Sound Demo</span>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```